# i've got a bug when exporting my game on android UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm facing an issue with the orientation of my Unity game on different devices. The game UI remains in the right position, but the game itself rotates inconsistently. I've tried several solutions to fix this problem, including adjusting player settings, camera settings, UI settings, and scripts, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

if anyone knows how to fix, please answer it.